# avoid using sudo to use z3++.h as a lib

Tags: z3

I am using the z3prover first time, after reading most of related answers, I have noticed that I need to try: sudo make install   .How could I skip the link z3 in /usr/bin and /usr/lib to use z3++.h in my own c++ project. (bcs I have noticed not everyone has the sudoer, I hope my code would goes well without sudoer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to compile the z3 source code if you want to be able to use it in your C/C++ projects. Compiling it will give you the library to link against. If you just download the source code, you can find the headers but you cannot link and hence cannot create your own executables.

But doing so does not require `sudo` access at all. The proper way to do so is actually explained in the https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 page, right in the README. Roughly, they go like this:

```
python scripts/mk_make.py --prefix=/home/leo
cd build
make
make install
```

Note in the `prefix` parameter of the first line you tell z3 where to install everything. Change that path to a place where you have write-access. This way you do not need `sudo` access.

In order to compile your project successfully, you need to tell your compiler where to look for dynamic libraries and header files. Ask separately if you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GCC` as the compiler you should add -I option for your project as follows :

```
g++ -Iz3_path/include -Lz3_path/lib  -lz3
```

Comment: thanks for your answering,  I am trying with `g++ -Iz3/src/api/c++ -Iz3/src/api tst.cpp 
-o tst `  tst.cpp only include z3++.h  , failed to compile   with the error code :              ` note: suggested alternative: ‘Z3_mk_seq_length’
  _M_set_length(__dnew);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
  Z3_mk_seq_length`

Comment: @guanqinzhang So if it's helpful please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @guanqinzhang It's possibly an error caused by using a wrong  name when calling a function.It's suggesting to use 'Z3_mk_seq_length' instead. It might be a typo

Comment: @ParsaMousavi This answer is wrong, unfortunately. You *do* have to compile, and the proper way is to call the python script that creates the configuration with the appropriate parameter. You do not need `sudo`. See my answer below.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi No problem, it happens. You should either delete your answer or modify it accordingly so future visitors aren't confused by it.

Comment: @alias I thought its api is completely standalone like header-only projects (e.g glm for OpenGL).

Comment: @alias Can I edit your post and add hints for linking against libz3.so and inclusion directories?

Comment: The exact location of the library and headers will depend on the operating system, how you specify them on the command line or environment, and other factors. It's best to let the user experiment and report what they have found and help from there. In particular on MacOSX, it doesn't go under `include` or `lib` like you have suggested. So, your answer is still misleading without knowing the exact specifics of what they want to do. (Also the whole question is really about `sudo` part, it's important to stick to the subject matter in your answers.)

Comment: @alias OK . You're absolutely right .And your post is more on-topic.But when I try to delete my post , it says "You cannot delete this accepted answer".

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Don't worry about it! When the OP comes back he can change the accepted answer, or leave it be. It's all part of stackoverflow workflows; and this'll resolve itself.